# Create folder during app install in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make simple notepad application for learning android development. So, to store the created text files can i create a folder into my application folder while application getting installed on android instead of creating folder using File class and then adding files to it in the code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to achieve that as your application doesn't really have any control or permissions untill its installed. Once the app is installed you can create the folder very instance the app starts.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, It is not possible to create a folder while installing Android Application. However you can design you code such that it creates folder while loading the Application for first time.

Answer (score 3):

Lucifer and Mayank are right.  here is what I did:

```
File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, filename);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

Wrap this in a try-catch block and it's safe.  Launch it on onCreate of your main activity and that's just fine

Use this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks kishu, that really helped..., but it seems i cannot access external storage while in android 2.1, i am trying to create file in current directory to phone memory for storing text files.