# External folder Create and Delete in SDCARD while installing and uninstalling application

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I'm making a music player app.

I want to create one folder during installation in `sd-card` (External Storage) and Delete while uninstalling application.

I tried to find a lot. there is no way to `delete external storage` while uninstalling application.Then i decided o make a function which will create a directory and it will be created only when application installed.

I tried it in application class but it is not possible because it is called every time application started.

Where should I put the `code(Create new directory)` so it must be called only and only installation time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920135/create-folder-during-app-install-in-android

Comment: I think you can only create the folder after the app has started the first time. Can you elaborate why you want to create the folder when the application is installed? You cannot do anything when the app is uninstalled by the OS because application code is not invoked, same with installation.

Comment: i want to store music file in that folder..

Comment: isn't it possible with broadcast receiver????????????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you check before creation if Directory already exists or not, I think that can fullfill your Requirement.

Although the code will be called every time but without any harm.

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Boolean isFirstTime;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

              addDirectory();

           }
    }





       public void addDirectory(){

            File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mDirectory");
            if(!direct.exists())
             {
                 if(direct.mkdir()); //directory is created;

             }


        }
```

Comment: i want to know that this code where should i put.i dont want nay answer of code...

Comment: call it in on create of your activity....
I have already mentioned it in my answer..

even then for your help updating my answer

Comment: yes bro. you are right but the songs are entried in database in application.so when application is uninstalled i have to remove it.but it is not possible.so when application installed i want to create that directory only at installtion time.if directory already exists then song will be available there but there will not be entry in Database.it may be problem in application

Comment: Ok lets go step by step----
Application installed->
created the directory(enteries in database for all songs that you have in your directory)
Unisntalled app-> (Database gone, directroy with songs in it still there).
Installeed app again ->(as directory already exist it will skip creating it, but database created)..

now this is your problem database is not having the values for that songs?

Comment: then when ever you will install app In the sample provided above There is a line which checks for if "Directory exist"
in side that line if directory exists then do something that will look for files in it and make entries for those files in database at the installation time..
Problem :- this code will run again and again...

So what you can do is save a boolean variable "isfirsttime" in SHARED PREFERENCES and cll this create directory check if this bool flag is false . which will be only when its first time at the the time of installation

Comment: if(!SharedPreferenceUtil.getBoolean("init", false))
  {
   createiAC_Directory();
   SharedPreferenceUtil.putValue("init", true);
   SharedPreferenceUtil.save();   
  }